# SharedPreferences is not saving android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 sharedpreferences that seems are not saving after app restarts. Hereunder my code.

This is my splash screen that creates the shared preferences :

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("LEVEL", 1);
    editor.putInt("COINS", 100);
    editor.commit();
```

When the app goes to the next activity, I play a bit with stored values and all seems to be working inside this activity. I put this on activity create

```
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
    curlevel = sharedPreferences.getInt("LEVEL", 0);
    goldcoins = sharedPreferences.getInt("COINS", 0);
```

Then I update the values accoring to the following function :

```
    public static void setPushEnabledFlag(Context context, String key ,int newValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
    Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.clear();
    prefsEditor.putInt(key, newValue);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

The values is restored to original values of the first activity everytime i restart the app.

Any help ?

Edit 1:

I have only 2 activites, Splash and game, In the first activity I have to create the shared preferences and assign 2 default values for the COINS and LEVEL. In the game activity I should get the default values if it's the first time the app initialize otherwise, It should retain the saved values from the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

avoid the use of the `clear()` method:

```
public static void setPushEnabledFlag(Context context, String key ,int newValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    //prefsEditor.clear();
    prefsEditor.putInt(key, newValue);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply however, The values are still restored to the orininals after app restarts :(

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, the splash screen activity code will run every time you start the app.

So your `SharedPreferences` is always overwritten in the splash. The solution is to move the code to a different place.

Comment: If i added this to the same activity which have a lot of calculation, It will be the same as everytime they will get the default values?

Comment: I need to know more about your flow, because the splash is the inital activity, which one do you refer to as first and second activity, please edit your question with more detail so we can sort it out

Answer (score 0):

Edit code as following code

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("App", context. MODE_PRIVATE);
    curlevel = sharedPreferences.getInt("LEVEL", "");
    goldcoins = sharedPreferences.getInt("COINS", "");
```

Comment: It won't allow me to user getInt with second argument ""? It advises me to use getFloat instead?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post that checks is the sharedpreferences exists or not and it works!!!

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    if(!sharedPrefs.contains("initialized")){
        ed = sharedPrefs.edit();

        //Indicate that the default shared prefs have been set
        ed.putBoolean("initialized", true);

        //Set some default shared pref
        ed.putInt("LEVEL", 1);
        ed.putInt("COINS", 100);

        ed.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it crashes again :(